# Generate certificate with custom encoding algorythm

Tags: encryption, certificate, makecert

MakeCert.exe certificate generation utility (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(VS.100).aspx) has -a (algorithm) parameter using for specifying the signature algorithm. Algorithm must be md5, sha1 (the default), sha256, sha384, or sha512.
I need to use russian hash algorythm standard - ГОСТ Р 34.11-94. Is it possible to do this? Or maybe should I use another parameter? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flag "eku" and specify oid. In you case oid is "1.2.643.2.2.9"